# Problem with DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute [Winform]

Tags: c#, winforms, design-time

I have a problem with a property which has a [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)] attribute :

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public String FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fileName;
        }

        set
        {
            File.Move(this._fileName, value);
            this._fileName = value;
        }
    }
```

If I comment the File.Move method, all is fine but I want to my fileName is renamed if the property FileName has changed in the properties window.

Why DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute don't accept a method in a setter ? Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you getting an error at compilation time, or at run-time... What error is coming back.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably enclose that `File.Move` statement in a Try...Catch block.

Of course, *having* a `File.Move` action in a property is probably not the best place to put code like that, especially since the Designer is firing that method every time it opens.